# Data is not inserting into Firebase Realtime Database throw Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, firebase-realtime-database

I have written simple Firebase Realtime Database code to insert data in it using android java code. Whenever i click on upload button then button is get clicked but firebase code is not  executed without showing any error message or warning about data insertion. I have tried to create many different new projects to test the same code but no work.

**My code:**

In below code none of any method is get invoked from SuccessListener() or FailureListener() but button got clicked.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==uploadBtn.getId()){ 

    DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                TestModel tm=new TestModel("Angela","angela@123");
                ref.child("Angela").setValue(tm).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d("app","data inserted");
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d("app","failed to inserted: "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
}
```

Not getting any error message or warning from above code. And also there is no any change in the firebase database.

**My TestModel class:**

```
public class TestModel {
    public String name,passwd;

    public TestModel(String name, String passwd) {
        this.name = name;
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }
}
```

**Rules:**

```
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write":true
}
```

**Firebase Node Structure:**

```
first-app-default-rtdb:null
```

**build.gradle (Project):**

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.simpleapp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

**I have tried below but same issue:**

- Upgraded studio to 2020.3
- Added Getter and Setters
- New project created for checking
- Select,Update,Delete also tried to do
- .Json file added manually
- New google account created and connected
- Test app on Real and Emulator device (Version 7.0 - 11)
- Cleaned project several times. Removed and added firebase in gradle
- Migrated to android jetpack
- VPN and Normal connection tried
- Gradle plugins upgraded to latest version.
- Target device changed, MIN and Target version changed
- Antivirus blocked. Firewall disabled.
- Firebase rules changed.
- Database URL path added

Please help me.

Comment: Make sure you download the `google-services.json` **after** you created your database in the Firebase console, as otherwise it won't contain the correct URL. You can also try putting the URL of the database directly in the code: `DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("database URL here")`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have already followed this. But still not working. Can you please mention a proper link to follow connection steps with firebase android

Comment: Put a debug on this code block and check if it's executed

Comment: What is the exact location of your database?

Comment: @AlexMamo It shows: Database location: United States (us-central1)

Comment: Is onSuccess or onFailure even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo None of any method invoked from them.

Comment: Are you sure you have an internet connection on that device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in Internet connection of the Emulator. Device was offline. Because I have used my Phone's hotspot connection for the emulator. When hotspot was turned off and emulator started then emulator always stays in a offline mode until we restart it.

Information log or warning, error messages are expected for this problem from Firebase or Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I facing this issue from last 3 Days finally i found some solution

First thing update your json file

Second check read, Write Rules is True

Third Go to Project Seetting->Open Tab Data Usage-> Now You will see Product Section pls make sure you unenforced the dataBase if you Bymistake enforced that option
After this you will finally Read or Write the Data in DataBase

Thanks

Happy Caoding

Here Check Screen Short for unenforced data Like this
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0pzI.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with the following possible solutions:**

1. Check service JSON file is placed under the app folder.
2. Check-in the firebase console and your database reference is valid or not null.

Answer (score 0):

Add setter methods in your class and then try again.

Comment: Generated both Getters & Setter but still no change.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and now I found that problem was firebase data central setting in google-services.json file. Before I set my data center other than US_Central, I downloaded and put json file in app folder. This causes to not find database file because of different URL for Belgium. I hope this helps to others in case they have similar problems